# How to pass a variable from one task to another in airflow

Tags: python, python-3.x, airflow, airflow-2.x

The below code works but my requirement is to pass totalbuckets as an input to the function as opposed to global variable. I am having trouble passing it as a variable and do xcom_pull in next task. This dag basically creates buckets based on the number of inputs and totalbuckets is a constant. Appreciate your help in advance.

```
from airflow import DAG    
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator, BranchPythonOperator   
with DAG('test-live', catchup=False, schedule_interval=None, default_args=args) as test_live:


totalbuckets = 3


# branches based on number of buckets
    def branch_buckets(**context):

        buckets = defaultdict(list)
        for i in range(len(inputs_to_process)):
            buckets[f'bucket_{(1+i % totalbuckets)}'].append(inputs_to_process[i])
      
        for bucket_name, input_sublist in buckets.items():
            context['ti'].xcom_push(key = bucket_name, value = input_sublist)
        return list(buckets.keys())
    
    # BranchPythonOperator will launch the buckets and distributes inputs among the buckets
    branch_buckets = BranchPythonOperator(
        task_id='branch_buckets',
        python_callable=branch_buckets,
        trigger_rule=TriggerRule.NONE_FAILED,
        provide_context=True,
        dag=test_live
    )  
# update provider tables with merge sql
    def update_inputs(sf_conn_id, bucket_name, **context):
        input_sublist = context['ti'].xcom_pull(task_ids='branch_buckets', key=bucket_name)
        print(f"Processing inputs {input_sublist} in {bucket_name}")

        from custom.hooks.snowflake_hook import SnowflakeHook
        for p in input_sublist:
            merge_sql=f"""
            merge into ......"""

bucket_tasks = []
        for i in range(totalbuckets):
            task= PythonOperator(
                task_id=f'bucket_{i+1}',
                python_callable=update_inputs,
                provide_context=True,
                op_kwargs={'bucket_name':f'bucket_{i+1}','sf_conn_id': SF_CONN_ID},
                dag=test_live
            )
            bucket_tasks.append(task)
```

Comment: What is the Xcom value that's being pulled right now?

Comment: What's the ultimate goal? Is it to create some dynamic, arbitrary number of buckets or to create a relatively static number of buckets? Do you just want to abstract `totalbuckets` into an [Airflow Variable](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts/variables.html) or does `totalbuckets` depend on the result of a previous task?

Answer (score 0):

If `totalbuckets` is different from run to other, it should be a run conf variable, you can provide it for each run crated from the UI, CLI, Airflow REST API or even python API.

```py
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator, BranchPythonOperator
from airflow.models.param import Param
with DAG(
    'test-live',
    catchup=False,
    schedule_interval=None,
    default_args=args,
    params={"totalbuckets": Param(default=3, type="integer")},
) as test_live:
    # branches based on number of buckets
    def branch_buckets(**context):

        buckets = defaultdict(list)
        for i in range(len(inputs_to_process)):
            buckets[f'bucket_{(1+i % int("{{ params.totalbuckets }}"))}'].append(inputs_to_process[i])

        for bucket_name, input_sublist in buckets.items():
            context['ti'].xcom_push(key = bucket_name, value = input_sublist)
        return list(buckets.keys())

    # BranchPythonOperator will launch the buckets and distributes inputs among the buckets
    branch_buckets = BranchPythonOperator(
        task_id='branch_buckets',
        python_callable=branch_buckets,
        trigger_rule=TriggerRule.NONE_FAILED,
        provide_context=True,
        dag=test_live
    )
    # update provider tables with merge sql
    def update_inputs(sf_conn_id, bucket_name, **context):
        input_sublist = context['ti'].xcom_pull(task_ids='branch_buckets', key=bucket_name)
        print(f"Processing inputs {input_sublist} in {bucket_name}")

        from custom.hooks.snowflake_hook import SnowflakeHook
        for p in input_sublist:
            merge_sql=f"""
                merge into ......"""

    bucket_tasks = []
    for i in range(int("{{ params.totalbuckets }}")):
        task= PythonOperator(
            task_id=f'bucket_{i+1}',
            python_callable=update_inputs,
            provide_context=True,
            op_kwargs={'bucket_name':f'bucket_{i+1}','sf_conn_id': SF_CONN_ID},
            dag=test_live
        )
        bucket_tasks.append(task)
```

Example to run it:

```bash
airflow dags trigger --conf '{"totalbuckets": 10}' test-live
```

Or via the [UI](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/dag-run.html#using-ui).

### update:

And if it's static, but different from an environment to other, it can be an [Airflow variable](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/variable.html), and read it directly in the tasks using jinja to avoid reading it at each Dag Files processing.

But if it's completely static, the most recommended solution is using python variable as you do, because to read dag run conf and Airflow variables, the task/dag send a query to the database.

Comment: Thankyou for your response. I do not want to pass the value each time the dag runs. totalbuckets will be a static value but I do no want to declare it as a global variable.

Answer (score -1):

@hussein awala I am doing something like below but cannot parse totalbuckets in bucket_tasks

````
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator, BranchPythonOperator   
with DAG('test-live', catchup=False, schedule_interval=None, default_args=args) as test_live:


#totalbuckets = 3


    def branch_buckets(totalbuckets, **context):

        buckets = defaultdict(list)
        for i in range(len(inputs_to_process)):
            buckets[f'bucket_{(1+i % totalbuckets)}'].append(inputs_to_process[i])
      
        for bucket_name, input_sublist in buckets.items():
            context['ti'].xcom_push(key = bucket_name, value = input_sublist)
        return list(buckets.keys())
    
    # BranchPythonOperator will launch the buckets and distributes inputs among the buckets
    branch_buckets = BranchPythonOperator(
        task_id='branch_buckets',
        python_callable=branch_buckets,
        trigger_rule=TriggerRule.NONE_FAILED,
        provide_context=True, op_kwargs={'totalbuckets':3},
        dag=test_live
    )  
# update provider tables with merge sql
    def update_inputs(sf_conn_id, bucket_name, **context):
        input_sublist = context['ti'].xcom_pull(task_ids='branch_buckets', key=bucket_name)
        print(f"Processing inputs {input_sublist} in {bucket_name}")

        from custom.hooks.snowflake_hook import SnowflakeHook
        for p in input_sublist:
            merge_sql=f"""
            merge into ......"""

bucket_tasks = []
        for i in range(totalbuckets):
            task= PythonOperator(
                task_id=f'bucket_{i+1}',
                python_callable=update_inputs,
                provide_context=True,
                op_kwargs={'bucket_name':f'bucket_{i+1}','sf_conn_id': SF_CONN_ID},
                dag=test_live
            )
            bucket_tasks.append(task)```
````

Comment: Please update your question or reply in a comment